# node.js v5.3 child_process.fork lost stdout occasionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, stderr, child-process

I'm using `child_process` in node.js to handle some task concurrentlly, and pipe `main process`'s stdout stderr into some log file.

when using `console.log` or `console.info` in `child.js`, these data lost in occasionally.

Here is my `main.js` :

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;


var filePath = './child.js';

function runChild( conf ){
        var child = fork(filePath, {
                env : {
                        index : conf.index,
                        name : conf.name
                }
        } );
        child.on('exit', function(code, signal){
                console.log(`[main] child[${conf.name}] exit, code=[${code}], signal=[${signal}]`);
        });

        child.unref();

}

for( var i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++ ){
        runChild({
                index : i,
                name : 'child_' + i
        });
}
```

and `child.js`:

```
var index = process.env.index;
var name = process.env.name;

setTimeout(function(){
        console.info(`[child] run in child: index=[${index}]`);

        setTimeout(function(){
                console.info(`[child] before exit: index=[${index}]`);
                process.exit(0);
        }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

run `node main.js > log.txt 2>&1`, sometimes log.txt looks like:

```
[child] run in child: index=[0]
[child] run in child: index=[3]
[child] run in child: index=[1]
[child] run in child: index=[2]
[child] before exit: index=[0]
[main] child[child_0] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[child] before exit: index=[3]
[main] child[child_3] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[child] before exit: index=[1]
[main] child[child_1] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[child] before exit: index=[2]
```

and sometimes output is this:

```
[child] run in child: index=[0]
[child] run in child: index=[1]
[child] run in child: index=[2]
[child] run in child: index=[3]
[child] before exit: index=[0]
[main] child[child_0] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[main] child[child_2] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[main] child[child_3] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
[main] child[child_1] exit, code=[0], signal=[null]
```

this only happens OCCASIONALLY.

Any advice is appreciated, thx in advance.